# Swing sample form application

Tags: java, swing

I have come up with the below code:

```
    String[] labels = {"Name: ", "Fax: ", "Email: ", "Address: "};
    int numPairs = labels.length;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SpringDemo1");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Set up the content pane.

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
    contentPane.setLayout(layout);

    for (int i = 0; i < numPairs; i++)
    {
        JLabel lable = new JLabel(labels[i]);
        contentPane.add(lable);
        contentPane.add(new JTextField(15));
    }
    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

**Expectation:**

[image]

**What I am getting:**
Default:

[image]

---

when resized:

[image]

The result is noway related to how code actually/normally looks like!

I also tried copy pasting and running the ready-made code: downloaded from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/SpringDemo1Project/src/layout/SpringDemo1.java):

and this is how the result looks :

[image]

Comment: There is a handy tutorial on this issue: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html

Comment: @Default locale, I tried to run copying code from same source the result looks like I have updated in my question..

Comment: if u go further down in the link provided by @defaultlocale then you see the exact same "error" and how to solve this issue

Comment: Keep reading the article... the code you copy and pasted is supposed to fail - they are using it as an example.

Comment: @GeekWorking Just read the tutorial. It even gives an example of [very](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/figures/uiswing/layout/SpringDemo1.png) [similar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/figures/uiswing/layout/SpringDemo1-resized.png) display problems and shows the ways to resolve these issues

Comment: my bad .. too furious to conquer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To put the components in the right place using SpringLayout, you should use the  ( [SpringUtilities class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/SpringGridProject/src/layout/SpringUtilities.java) ), download it then include it in your project. 
your code should be:

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    String[] labels = {"Name: ", "Fax: ", "Email: ", "Address: "};
    int numPairs = labels.length;

    //Create and populate the panel.
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new SpringLayout());
    for (int i = 0; i < numPairs; i++) {
        JLabel l = new JLabel(labels[i], JLabel.TRAILING);
        p.add(l);
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        l.setLabelFor(textField);
        p.add(textField);
    }

    //Lay out the panel.
    SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(p,
                                    numPairs, 2, //rows, cols
                                    6, 6,        //initX, initY
                                    6, 6);       //xPad, yPad

    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SpringForm");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Set up the content pane.
    p.setOpaque(true);  //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(p);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

i hope that helps you!